# How to disable the "auto format" feature of VisualStudio2008 editor?

Tags: visual-studio

When writing the HTML part of a page in a VS2008 Web App, the editor keeps formatting the HTML with linebreaks that break the readability of the code (to my eyes).
Can this feature be disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Tools/Options/Text Editor/HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Tool/Options/

[Show all settings]

Text Editor/HTML

Wrap tags when exceeding specified lenght

If any interested.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at the Tag Wrapping option inside the Text Editor -> HTML options under the text editor settings. You can either disable it altogether or extend it beyond the 80 character default.

However, there is still some level of code reformatting that happens behind the scenes when you drag new controls into the page that I haven't found any solution to other than just staying in the text editor as much as possible.

Two good things to note: 1. VS2K8 does a MUCH better job that VS2K5 when it comes to formatting HTML. 2. With the new intellisense built into VS2K8, it makes it really easy to stay in the text editor while adding tags. I think I do most of my HTML stuff there now. You can keep your display in "split view" and just refresh every now and then to see how your controls are coming up.